# How to retrieve the value of key in array with jq?

Tags: bash, jq

How can I get the id value if name equals to `y` in cli?

JSON input :

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "x",
      "name": "y"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried this

```
json file | jq -r '.items | select(.name=="y")
```

it returns

> jq: error (at :1): Cannot index array with string "name"` error

How to retrieve the value of name only via jq?

Thanks!

Comment: `.items[] | select(.name == "y").id` will output `x`

Comment: As an aside, the pseudo-pipe `json file | ` is not correct. It looks like maybe you were trying to do a [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) but botching it.